# how many boolean functions have exactly one non-zero fourier coefficient?

Tags: boolean-expression

This question is part of the book **Analysis of Boolean functions**, by Ryan O'donnell.

I did try to understand the the concept of boolean functions by watching the [video lecture](https://scs.hosted.panopto.com/Panopto/Pages/Viewer.aspx?id=ec417c23-9ced-4dbb-9652-de9ae4b76ecb) of the author.
What I inferred was that, the number of non-zero fourier coefficients can only be a power of two. I think, due to this, exactly one coefficient is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

If a Boolean function has exactly one non-zero fourier coefficient then it is equal to $$\pm \chi_S$$ for some $$S$$. Hence, there are exactly $$2^{n+1}$$ Boolean functions with exactly one nonzero fourier coefficient.